# Not able to add GIF in flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I have a chat screen  text box and a button. I want user to be able to select gif offered by keyboard and then insert into chat screen.

TextFormField does not allow user to select GIF. Code is as follows:

video link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzzTT.jpg

> Error - testapp doesn't support image insertion here.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: TextFormField(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems there's an open issue for this. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20796

Answer (score 4):

Flutter's `TextField`, `TextFormField` or any text input boxes do not accept characters other than the ones specified in [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/).

To use GIFs, images or any other widgets in a TextField, try using [`extended_text_field`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field) package.This is **NOT** an official package but it was planed to be endorsed by the flutter team according to [#30688 (comment)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30688#issuecomment-519716702).

**extended_text_field** provides a widget named [`SpecialText`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field#speical-text). You could use the [`ImageSpan`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field#imagespan) widget to add images in the text field (which includes GIFs).

Comment: Can you please show the code we can put to use this widget?